# Why is one of my nested react route not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React view component that looks roughly like the one in the code below. The problem I have is the nested `/:handle/saved` route doesn't match the corresponding component and, thus, I'm redirected to the NotFound page.

I have nested routes in other pages of the app that work fine, so what am I missing here?

Below is the code corresponding to the page component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { func, object } from 'prop-types';
import { NavLink, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Grid, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

function ProfilePage() {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Row className={row}>
        <Grid.Column className={column}>
          <NavLink
            style={{ margin: '0 2rem 0 0' }}
            className={link}
            activeStyle={{ borderTop: '2px solid #333333' }}
            to='/johndoe'
          >
            <Icon className={icon} name='grid layout' size='small' /> Posts
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            style={{ margin: '0 0 0 2rem' }}
            className={link}
            activeStyle={{ borderTop: '2px solid #333333' }}
            to='/johndoe/saved'
          >
            <Icon className={icon} name='bookmark outline' size='small' />{' '}
            Saved
          </NavLink>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Row className={row}>
        <Grid.Column className={column}>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path='/:handle'
              component={() => <div>I am Groot</div>}
            />
            <Route
              path='/:handle/saved'
              component={() => <div>I am Groot: Saved</div>}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the route with `/:handle/saved`  before `/:handle`

But this can also ve a typo?? Maybe instead of `/:handle/saved` it should be `/:handle/:saved` with `:` before `saved`

Also try addind `exact` to the route with `/:handle/saved`

## Edit:

Please check your console, do you have any errors?

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-one-of-my-nested-react-route-not-working-nj7n8).

You could try adding `BrowserRouter` around your component, that is the only thing I added and it's working as expected.

Comment: saved is not variable (not a parameter), so having it as :saved is unnecessary. Also, I already tried adding the exact prop but to no avail. Switching their positions wouldn't work either. I'll try adding BrowserRouter, but I feel like it's unnecessary.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando that is kind of weird because in the codesandbox, it's working

Comment: @CollinsOrlando can you add more information on the nested routes?

Comment: @Venconvsky See,this link https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-field-6n91u redirects to a simplified structure of my app. Hell, even here the routes works fine here, but wont work on my app. 

Like I mentioned, I have other nested routes that are working fine, so it's a really strange phenomenon.

Comment: Read up a bit on react-router - which is something I ought to have done earlier - and learnt that adding exact props to the parent route prevents nesting routes. That was the source of my problem. Thanks, though, for the suggestions and overall help.